# What is the requirement for a binary executable in APP on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, build

We don't use the Xcode IDE for building the `.app`. We use a shell script to build it. We follow the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW13), but it seems the executable still cannot be loaded and the `.app` is invalid.

From the Mac documentation, the `.app` needs to contains following two parts:

- Info.plist:  RPK.app/Contents/Info.plist
- Executable:  RPK.app/Contents/MacOS/RPK

So we copy the following content to the `Info.plist` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>RPK</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>RPK</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.codetool.RPK</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>RPK</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>XCEL</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>12.2.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I create the executable using:

```
g++ -x objective-c++ main.mm -o RPK
```

main.mm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("HELLO WORD");
    return 0;
}
```

But it seems the `.app` still cannot be loaded, and the reason seems to be related to the executable.
So what's the executable requirement so the `APP` can be loaded (run) on a Mac.

Comment: what does the XCEL mean? I have only seen ????

Comment: It is just random four characters.

Comment: Not sure why you are choosing the hard way, but OK.   That main function is not a cocoa app.  See the main of a standard cocoa app.

Comment: @bbum, can you give more details? I have create an Cocoa app using Xcode, seams the main function in `main.m` is `int main(int argc, const char * argv[])`, and even I just have one line `return 0;` in `main`, it is ok to run, so what's the difference.

Comment: Start by creating a single window, dead simple, Cocoa app.  Now compare it to your app. There are massive differences and the `main` is one of them.  Specifically, your `main` does not call `NSApplicationMain()`.   Without knowing what you are really trying to achieve, it is impossible to say much more.

Comment: @bbum, but if I comments `NSApplicationMain()` in `main`. It still works in Xcode project.

Comment: @ZijingWu Then you still haven't manually created a project that meets the same requirements as the Xcode based template.  How are you constructing your UI?  Do you have a main menu?  App delegate?  How are you otherwise recreating everything in that stock, simple, Cocoa project in Xcode?